read sin respuesta en bash script
estoy intentando hacer un script donde necesito que el usuario introduza el directorio donde quiere se guarden los datos, el unico problema es que necesito que pueda dejar la respuesta vacia si quiere guardarlo en el directorio desde donde se ejecuta el script.
echo -e "${gray}Type the route to create backup image:${end}\n"
read -e route
if [ -z $route ]; then
    if [ ! -d $route ]; then
        mkdir -p $route
        echo "$route created successfully"
    fi
else
    echo -e "${gray}The backup will be saved in current directory $PWD${end}"
fi

hasta ahi todo bien el problema es que cuando el usuario deja la respuesta vacia, directamente el script no continua, directamente se para la ejecucion y no continua con lo que viene despues, ni muestra el mensaje que hay tras el else.

Type the route to create backup image:
$

Alguien sabra alguna manera de que esto pueda quedar vacio??
Muchas gracias.

Sustituya la prueba -z por -n.

Hubiera valido en parte, al poner -n la evaluacion estaria bien, pero la variable route seguiria sin asignar, habria que asignarla

No se que ha pasado con la respuesta que puso un usuario, era la correcta y muy bien redactada, pero ha desaparecido, supongo que el mismo la habra eliminado.
El problema era el siguiente, estaba haciendo mal la evaluacion y no estaba asignandole el valor a la varialbe. al final el codigo quedo de esta manera
echo -e "${gray}Type the route to create backup image:${end}\n"
read -e route
if [ -z $route ]; then
    route=$(pwd)
    echo -e "${gray}The backup will be saved in current directory $(pwd)${end}"
    sleep 2
else
    if [ ! -d $route ]; then
        mkdir -p $route
        echo "$route created successfully"
    fi
fi

Explicacion:
Lo primero es verificar si la variable esta vacia.
if [ -z $route ]; then

Si lo esta, le asignamos valor y ponemos el mensaje al usuario.
echo -e "${gray}The backup will be saved in current directory $(pwd)${end}"
sleep 2

En caso contrario, comprobamos si el directorio no existe y lo si es asi lo creamos
if [ ! -d $route ]; then
    mkdir -p $route
    echo "$route created successfully"
fi

De esta manera funciona perfectamente.
